# How can I determine my position by triangulation on known routers?

Tags: wifi, triangulation

Is there any open source software available? Basically, I just want to triangulate based on signal strength of routers whose location is fixed and known.

I realize there can be cases of interference, but let's just stick to listing known source code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution: http://redpin.org
They offer you for free for iOS and Android platforms. All sources you can download an look at. There bunch off documentation and other staff to help you with

Comment: I am change the awarded answer to this one, as it exactly meets my needs (with the added bonus that it is free). I am only surprised that Google haven't offered soemthing in the six years since I first posted this question

Answer (score 6):

I don't know of any trilateration software... someone should write an open source library.

Take a look at the [trilateration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) formulas.  They shouldn't be difficult to implement.  The hard thing to do will be to put your points and the router points onto a grid, and the measurements you have for the locations of your routers should inform your decision on how to do that.  Once you've mapped everything onto a grid, the formulas aren't complicated and shouldn't be difficult to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know any available software, but... this would be trivial to write given the signal strengths right?

1. Convert the signal strength into a distance
2. <strike>Triangulate</strike> Trilaterate the position (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration for the formulae)

Comment: Technically, what you need to do is Trilateration, not Triangulation.

Comment: @WhirlWind, +1 for the nice answer

Answer (score 1):

You might try these projects:
[WiFiPS](https://github.com/ajnas/WiFiPS) - WiFi Based Indoor Positioning System
[open_wps](https://github.com/toyokazu/open_wps) - WiFi Positioning System